# FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)

Tags: reactjs

I am using react js to upload images in firebase alongside its post contents i am able to post normal captions but when i try to post with image this error is showing up and cant upload image.

here is my code

```
 const handleUpload = (event) => {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0]) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0].classList.remove('hidden');
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName('postButton').disabled = true;
        document.getElementsByClassName('postButton')[0].classList.add('disabled');

        if (caption === "" && imageURL === "") {
            console.log("Prevented Access to Photo or Caption Submission")
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (imageURL === '') {
                db.collection("posts").add({
                    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                    caption: caption,
                    imageUrl: "",
                    noLikes: noLikes,
                    username: user?.displayName,
                    uid: user?.uid
                });
                handleClose();
                setProgress(0);
                setCaption("");
                setImage(null);
            } else {
                const uploadTask =  storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
                uploadTask.on(
                    "state_changed",
                    (snapshot) => {
                        const progress = Math.round(
                            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
                        );
                        setProgress(progress);
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        alert(error.message);
                    },
                    () => {
                        storage
                        
                            .ref("images")
                            .child(image.name)
                            .getDownloadURL()
                            .then(url => {
                                db.collection("posts").add({
                                    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                                    caption: caption,
                                    imageUrl: url,
                                    noLikes: noLikes,
                                    username: user?.displayName,
                                    uid: user?.uid
                                    
                                });
                                handleClose();
                                setProgress(0);
                                setCaption("");
                                setImage(null);
                            })
                    }
                )
            }
        }

    }
```

If I can get relevant examples it will be very helpful some says that the problem is that i am calling url before the image is not upload so i tried to add await but still does not work.